# How to properly publish Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) and remove console errors related to .pdb files

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdb-files, blazor-server-side

I am attempting to start a new Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) project and properly publish to linux-arm, linux-arm doesn't seem to be the issue at the moment.

I am able to get it running, however, Browser > Dev Tool > Console is showing the following errors:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/_framework/_bin/rpiServer.Client.pdb (404) Not Found  blazor.webassembly.js:1
GET http://localhost:5000/_framework/_bin/rpiServer.Client.pdb (404) Not Found  blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Having my startup project as rpiServer.Client or rpiServer.Server during Publish yields the same errors when all is setup on the RPI.

These are the steps I used to Publish and get the Hosting Environment running:

`dotnet publish -r linux-arm --output R:\...\rpiServer` (on Windows for the RPI), then on the RPI, executing `sudo chmod +755 ./rpiServer.Server` and finally `./rpiServer.Server` to start the website.

Note, I can find `_framework` folder but is isn't under the main folder, I first need to open `rpiServer.Client/dist/` to find the folder. I also tried to copy this folder to the root of the Website, no changes to the error messages.

Does anyone know the intended process/step for publishing and intended file structure.  I will provide more details when requested.